# Copying parameters from .env.dist to .env

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-3.4

I'm in the process of upgrading a project from Symfony 2.3 to Symfony 3.4 and I'm a bit confused about the relationship between .env and .env.dist files. From what I understand, the relationship between them is the same as the relationship between parameters.yml and parameters.yml.dist in Symfony2. But in the older Symfony, parameters.yml would be updated automatically during `composer update` after prompting the user about using the parameters in parameters.yml.dist as defaults. In Symfony3 documentation, on the other hand, I can't find any reference to automatic copying of parameters. Do the parameters in .env.dist always need to be copied to .env manually? If there is a way to copy them automaticaly, are there packages similar to [incenteev/composer-parameter-handler](https://packagist.org/packages/incenteev/composer-parameter-handler) that help with managing parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything like incenteev/composer-parameter-handler anymore. You can access ENV vars in your config. So you direclty use ENV vars in your config like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:   '%env(SYMFONY_DATABASE_NAME)%'
                user:     '%env(SYMFONY_DATABASE_USER)%'
                password: '%env(SYMFONY_DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
```

The .env files only allow you to add ENV vars. Symfony does specifically only recommend to use .env in non production environments.